# Shadow right and left across sections

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have seen plenty of code samples around this website about doing a shadow right and left and it is working fine for one section but when doing this on several sections I am getting a small gap between sections which doesn't look too good.

I have to use Bootstrap 3 https://codepen.io/Corobori/pen/ExgvdVO

```
    .container {
        background-color: white; 
        box-shadow: 5px 0 5px -5px #333,-5px 0 5px -5px #333;
    }
```

[image]

Should I wrap them to avoid this issue?

Comment: 5px 0 5px -5px makes the shadow 5px smaller, your code works fine. set the shadow (parent?)elsewhere or use a lighter color without reducing it :)

Comment: Used box-shadow: 1px 0 0 0 #999,-1px 0 0 0 #999;  and it looks better